# Is there a name for diseases associated with bone deformation?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

[Orthopaedics](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/orthopedics) is a branch of medical science concerning the skeletal system. Examples of orthopaedic disorders include arthritis, fibromyalgia, and lupus -- all of which come under the class of musculoskeletal disorders.

Other examples include scoliosis, kyphosis, and Paget disease, which are all concerned with bone deformation.I was thinking about calling them as *bone deformity disorders* but was hoping if there is an established 'fancier' name out there in the field for this purpose.

Is there an umbrella term that covers diseases that are associated with bone deformity?

Comment: Do you mean something well-known and recognizable to doctors, or to the general public? As a member of the laity I can say there's no single word or term that would call to my mind the full range of osseal disorders.

Comment: @JimMack Yes, I'm searching for a technical term used by members of the field. By the way, what does *osseal* mean? I couldn't find a definition anywhere for it.

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/osseous

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac  Generally, **osseal** means 'related to bone' while **osseous** means 'made of bone'.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac  I should also say that **osseal** is not as common a variant as **osteal** which means the same thing. The Latin root *ossum* is seen in the dish *osso buco* for example.

Comment: @JimMack: That may be the first time I've seen the term "laity" used in a nonreligious context.

Answer (score 1):

*Osteocampsia* means an abnormal curvature of bone.

Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary, 31st Edition (p. 1366) has this entry:

> *Osteocampsia:* curvature or bending of a bone, as in rickets.

One problem in generalizing, though, is that a disease like Paget disease of bone (osteitis deformans) has other manifestations besides long bone curvature, such as thickened flat bones. Also the term does not take into account the underlying pathology.

If you don't want to use a two-word label like *bone deformity*, I would think you could use a compound term like *osteodeformity* and be understood. Per Dorland's,

> *oste(o)-:* a combining form denoting relationship to a bone or to the bones. (p. 1365)
>
> *deformity:* distortion of any part or general disfigurement of the body (p. 486)

Comment: Would hallux valgus (bunions) would also come under Osteocampsia?

Comment: I'm not certain. The definition of "valgus" is "bent or twisted; denoting a deformity in which the angulation of the part is away from the midline of the body." (And "hallux" being the great toe.) With a bunion, I'm not sure the bones of the great toe are actually curved. It is a deformity, but I'm not sure it is a result of bone curvature. Maybe there is a physician on the site who can answer that.